# Use enum types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, enums, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm kinda new in powershell (expected start of message :)).
I wasn't been able to find answer on my question here or somewhere else, so could somebody help me, please?

For example, we want to use some enum declared in .NET libraries. How we use it in .NET? Kind of like:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Test {
   var x = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

If I need to use it in powershell, as I understood I need to write something like:

```
$x = [System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder]::Ascending
```

So, the question is, is it possible in powershell to use something like 'using' as in C# to shorten the syntax to kind of like: `$sortOrder.Ascending` or `[SortOrder]::Ascending`?

Comment: The term you are looking for is Type Accelerator (this is what it's called). If you google for Powershell Type Accelerator you'll find a lot of information (including that the using statement is introduced in PSv5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**

Store the enum type in a variable:

```
$so = [System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder]
$so::Ascending
```

**Option 2**

Create a custom [type accelerator](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/08/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) (for the current session only):

```
[PSObject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Add("so", "System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder")
[so]::Ascending
```

**Option 3** (PSv5+)

Introduced in PowerShell v5: add a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-6) to your `$profile`:

```
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

# in your script:
[SortOrder]::Ascending
```

**Option 4**

Use a string. In most scenarios (when the target type is known, e.g. for method calls, property assignments etc.) it will be recognized and converted automatically.

For example, if you have this type:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Example
{
    public class MyClient
    {
       public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can simply do this:

```
$myClient = New-Object Example.MyClient
$myClient.SortOrder = "Ascending"
```

Or also for explicitly typed variables:

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder]$sortOrder = "Ascending"
```

It's case sensitive and even accepts partial input as long as it's unambiguous:

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder]$sortOrder = "asc"
```

Comment: And because Jeffrey Snover is flawed, you can get away with "a". You need to give it just enough letters, so it's not ambiguous. :)

Comment: @Palansen You're right. I rarely use that though and it's horrible to read (except for the "asc" version maybe)